# C# Получение Ip host mac локальной сети

Tags: c#, ip

Нужно вывести все айдпи,хосты и мак адреса всей локальной сети.

Проблема в том что выдает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;


namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int SendARP(int destIp, int srcIP, byte[] macAddr, ref uint physicalAddrLen);

        List<TableHost> _host = new List<TableHost>();
        string hostname = "";
        IPHostEntry entry;
        string[] ipToString = new string[4];

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            // Получение ip-адреса.
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];


        }


        //System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];

        private void LL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            int i = int.Parse(ipToString[0]);
            int j = int.Parse(ipToString[1]);
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
                {
                    for (int m = 0; m < 254; m++)
                    {
                        //Запускаем проверку в новом потоке
                        Thread _thread = new Thread(() => GetInform(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", i.ToString(), j.ToString(), k.ToString(), m.ToString())));
                        _thread.Start();
                    }
                }
            }


        }


        private void GetInform(string textName)
        {
            string IP_Address = "";
            string HostName = "";
            string MacAddress = "";

            try
            {
                //Проверяем существует ли IP
                entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(textName);
                foreach (IPAddress a in entry.AddressList)
                {
                    IP_Address = a.ToString();
                    break;
                }

                //Получаем HostName
                HostName = entry.HostName;

                //Получаем Mac-address
                IPAddress dst = IPAddress.Parse(textName);

                byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
                uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

                if (SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(dst.GetAddressBytes(), 0), 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) != 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("SendARP failed.");

                string[] str = new string[(int)macAddrLen];
                for (int i = 0; i < macAddrLen; i++)
                    str[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");

                MacAddress = string.Join(":", str);

                //Далее, если всё успешно, добавляем все данные в список, после чего выводим всё в ListView
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    _host.Add(new TableHost() { ipAdress = IP_Address, nameComputer = HostName, MacAdress = MacAddress });
                    ListIP.ItemsSource = null;
                    ListIP.ItemsSource = _host;
                }));
            }
            catch { }

        }
    }
        class TableHost
        {
            public string ipAdress { get; set; }
            public string nameComputer { get; set; }
            public string MacAdress { get; set; }
        }



}
```

Проект [Скачать](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g536tuwFLF5jJ2RZARN41A6jPMYhzBf6)

Comment: потому что вы проинициализировали массив ipToString, в котором у вас 4 элемента со значением по умолчанию, а как знаем, default(string) = null, вот отсюда и ошибка приведения null к int. пользуйтесь точками остонова в дебаг режиме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил вот такое

```html
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            // Получение ip-адреса.
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];
           
            ipToString = ip.ToString().Split('.');
           


        }
```